# Last Laravel controller function loses data

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, request, laravel-8

I'm sending parameters from one to another without passing them through the route pass them another way for security, but the problem with the last function is that it loses the parameter and even `dd()` doesn't work, it returns the view only with an undefined variable `$data`.

**Controller**

```php
// Pass id to test.auth
public function show_auth($id)
{
    return view('test.auth', compact('id'));
}

// Here it gets id and dd($data) works
public function post_auth(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;

    $data = DB::table('kuponai')->where('id', $id)->get();
    //dd($data);
    
    return view('test.view', compact('data'));
}

// Function from before dump doesn't work and returns view
public function view($data)
{
    dump($data);

    return view('test.view');
}
```

Changed for this doesn't work neither...

```
public function check(Request $request)
    {
      $id = $request->id;

      //
      
      return view('test.auth',compact('id'));
      
    }
    public function show_auth($id)
    {
        return view('test.auth',compact('id'));
        
    }
    public function post_auth(Request $request)
    {
      $id = $request->id;
      $pin = $request->pin;
      $mail = $request->elpastas;

      $data = DB::table('kuponai')
      ->where('id', $id)
      ->get();
      //dd($data);

      return route('view.show',compact('data'));
    }
    public function view($data)
    {
      $d = $this->post_auth($data);
      //dd($data);
        return view('test.view');
    }
```

Comment: if you are accessing a method in the same controller use `$this->view($data);` `view()` are helper to call blade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because the data variable you passed is sent directly to the `test.view` view. So never pass the view function ($ data) you do `dump($data)`.

($ data is sent not via a route, but directly into the view) !!

I seem to know the solution, but please show me your snippet of routes.php

Routes:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'coupons.domain.com'], function()
{

        Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@index')->name('view.klientas');
        Route::post('/check', 'App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@check')->name('check')->middleware('checkid');
        // view authenticated coupon
        Route::get('/view', 'App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@view')->name('view.show')->middleware('checkpin');
        // show coupon authenticate form
        Route::get('/auth','App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@show_auth')->name('show.auth')->middleware('checkid');
        // handle user input, authenticate coupon
        Route::post('/authenticate','App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@post_auth')->name('post.auth')->middleware('checkpin');
});
```

Try to replace `return view('test.auth', compact('data'));`

With:
`return redirect('/view')->with(compact('data'));`

My middlewares:

checkid:

```
class KuponoId {

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
        $exists =Kuponas::where('id', $request->id)->exists();
        if (!$exists) {
            return \Redirect::to(url('/'))->with('pin','Duomenys neteisingi, patikrinkite ');
        }
        return $next($request);
  }
}
```

checkpin:

```
class CheckPin {

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
        $exists = Kuponas::where('patvirtinimo_kodas', $request->pin)->where('elpastas', $request->elpastas)->where('id', $request->id)->exists();
        //dd($exists);
        if (!$exists) {
          //return \Redirect::to(url('/'))->with('pin','Duomenys neteisingi, patikrinkite ');
          return \Redirect::to(url('/'))->with('pin','Duomenys neteisingi! ');
        }
        return $next($request);
  }
}
```

i just need to show info view for just that one time when user authentificates correctly

Oke, hhow about this?

return redirect()->action( 'TheController@view', ['id' => 1] );

Comment: my routes without parameters it's sensitive info where i can put snippet?

Comment: I just want to know the form of the route that leads to the view function ($ data). whether "/view" or "view/{id}"

Comment: the solution is to use `return redirect ('/view')->compact($data);` to replace `return view ('test.view', compact('data'));`

Comment: the goal is that the $data variable is routed through the view function ($data) instead of directly displaying the $data variable on the view (test.view)

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::compact()

Comment: try this`return redirect('/view')->with(compact('data'));` . Sorry, no `$` when using compact

Comment: now i can't  pass my midelware. Which checks if pin mail and id of coupon exists. So i need just $id to get data in my view for one time only.

Comment: How about this one? `return redirect()->action( 'TheController@view', ['id' => 1] );`

Comment: in which function should i put this? in show_auth();?

Comment: i think so . . .

Comment: still doesn't middleware if i use something like that in controller...